# Android ArrayAdapter not properly converting Views

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, android-viewholder

I have a custom `ArrayAdapter` for a `ListView` that uses a custom row layout, defined separately in XML.  The layout is just three `TextViews` and an `ImageView`, put together in a `RelativeLayout`.  To improve performance, the adapter uses a ViewHolder system like the one described [here](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html) to convert existing Views instead of inflating new ones.  In `ArrayAdapter.getView()`, the adapter is supposed to bold or unbold the first TextView, depending on a boolean.

When I first open the app, all of the TextViews are properly bolded or unbolded.  However, if I scroll to the bottom of the ListView, then scroll back to the top, all of the title TextViews are bold, even if they aren't supposed to be.  I think it must have something to do with converting existing views that are already bold, but I can't figure out what it is.  I've debugged the app with Android Studio, and it runs just like I think it should -- when I scroll back up, the adapter properly bolds/unbolds things in the debug window, but they all seem to be bold on the app.

One thing I have noticed is that if I change the `textStyle` attribute of the TextView to "bold," all the title TextViews are bold from the beginning, and never change.  It's only if I remove `textStyle` or set it to "normal" that the TextViews are normal at the start.

Here's getView() in the ArrayAdapter:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    PostShell shell = postShellList.get(getCount() - 1 - position); //I stack my ListView backwards, so index 0 is at the bottom
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.firstLine = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.firstLine);
        holder.secondLine = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.secondLine);
        holder.thirdLine = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.thirdLine);
        holder.image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    holder.firstLine.setText(shell.postTitle);
    if (shell.unread) {
        holder.firstLine.setTypeface(holder.firstLine.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD);
    } else {
        holder.firstLine.setTypeface(holder.firstLine.getTypeface(), Typeface.NORMAL);
    }
    //convert other TextViews
}
```

My ViewHolder class is just a static class with a few TextViews and an ImageView.

And here's the relevant part of the code for the row layout I'm using:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="88dp">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="84dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="6dp"
    android:id="@+id/firstLine"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:text="First"
    android:textStyle="normal"
    android:singleLine="true" />

<!-- other views -->

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: the curse of copy-and-paste... Thanks for fixing my answer :)

Comment: @0X0nosugar No problem, thanks for answering!  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that "unboldening" the text does not work with the following statement:

> holder.firstLine.setTypeface(holder.firstLine.getTypeface(), Typeface.NORMAL);

The following snippet leaves out the `holder.firstLine.getTypeface()` and just uses a simpler variety of `setTypeface()`. Worked for me.

```
if (shell.unread) {
    holder.firstLine.setTypeface(holder.firstLine.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD);
} else {
    holder.firstLine.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
PostShell shell = postShellList.get(getCount() - 1 - position); //I stack my ListView backwards, so index 0 is at the bottom
```

If the `ListView` asks for the element at a particular position, you'd better give it the element at that position or it's going to be confused. IF you want to alter the order of the items in the list, change the order of the list, don't try to trick `ListView` into rendering it in a different order.

Answer (score 0):

You should store your views in the normal order and use [`android:stackFromBottom`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#attr_android:stackFromBottom) or  [`setStackFromBottom()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setStackFromBottom%28boolean%29).